# My phone keep restarting for no reason (android)

Tags: android

Yesterday i was downgraded my OPPO A37f using ColorOS, because i want to get root access. everything is ok since 1 hour ago my phone keep restarting and idk why. suddenly hang and restart for almost 3 times then everything is normal. this also happened long time ago when my phone get rooted, yes same situation. i can turn on but about 15-30 seconds after turning on then my phone is hang for almost 1-2 mins then restarting and keep repeating. can anyone help me to find what is the problem? because i dont know anything about android program. then how to fix this problem too. thankyou so much.

Comment: wipe data or Flash ROM again

Comment: wow really? i dont want to redownload all my big size apps. if thats only the way then i dont need to ask here. everyone know to do that.

Comment: i know about backup but my app need to be redownloaded for its data.

Comment: You bricked it, you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reinstall it, fail rooting method may cause boot loop.
if it still occur after reinstall just revert back to normal OS

Comment: i still can get into android system not only welcome screen ui. i think thats not a bootloop. isnt it?

Comment: so you can use your phone such as open browser after booting?
i used to change os to my android and if its fail to run corectly i wont reinstall it or revert to stable version of the OS. its still best solution about OS installing

Comment: and what do you mean about fail rooting method? yesterday everything works fine. downloaded gltools and kernel auditor also everything is working fine. and i dont change anything until this thing happened.

Comment: yes i can open anything until its reach 'timeout'. if this thing happening, my phone will booting correctly for almost 15-30 secs (im saying this is a timeout bcs i dont know what) then hang and restart.

Comment: if its the problem for the 15 minutes after your phone boot find any service that your phone run, there must be some service that cause the system fail and force it to restart. 
*use force stop at app service that you suspect cause the reboot problem

Comment: that what i mean fail rooting method one of the service fail to start or corupted after installing somthing

Comment: oh ok will try it later. thanks bro :)